# Install4J: how to log and how to switch to console mode?

Tags: logging, install4j

Good afternoon,
I am new at working with Install4J (I'm trying to make a demo for replacing our current installation software by Install4J), and there are some basics I am struggling with:
I would like to log what is happening. I have seen an "installation.log" which was built but now it seems that this file is not written anymore. What do I need to do to get the logs created again? (I have already launched the automatically created "debug_installer.bat" Windows batchfile, but once I start creating big installers, I might fall into the size limits of the console window.
While looking at the helpfile, I have the impression that my version (install4j Multi-Platform Edition 6.0.3 (build 6091)) does not correspond to the screenshots, present in the helpfile.
One thing which would really be interesting, is a list of examples of Install4J projects, e.g. at this moment I am trying to read the registry, I think I have put everything correctly in the "Read a value from the Windows Registry" but still an error is returned, most probably because of some parameter I don't know of. Is there a place where I can look and learn?

Thanks
Dominique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log file will initially be created in the `%TEMP%` directory, with a name that starts with "i4jlog".

When the "Install files" action runs, the log file will be moved to the `.install4j/installation.log` file in the installation directory. If the installer fails before that, the partial log file will remain in the `%TEMP%` directory.